# Detecting keys pressed on a div

Tags: angularjs

I need to detect keys pressed on a div. [In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/89hBoZsJT6aC8LSEa0q5?p=preview) I have a div, but if I first click on it and then press a key (for example Del) then no event happens. How to make this work?

HTML

```
Click on the div and press a key:
<div ng-keypress="pressedKey($event)">

</div>
Key pressed: {{myKey}}
```

Javascript

```
angular.module("app", [])

.controller('ctl', function($scope) {

    $scope.pressedKey = function(event) {
        $scope.myKey = event.key;
      }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The div needs to be focusable. Just add

```
tabindex="0"
```

as an attibute on the div.

[Demo](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/qPlUE8pj1h83XvJj)

Comment: `Del` key is not detected, how to make that work?

Comment: got it, need to use `ng-keydown`

Comment: Nice answer :) - to remove blue glow use CSS `outline: none;`